# Where can I view this patent application?

Tags: prior-art

This [blog post says](http://labs.hybris.com/patent-pending/) that this patent has now been filed.

Can I view the patent on a database anywhere? I'm going to attempt to look for prior art.

Comment: That combination of physical technology definitely isn't novel, most of the introductory project books for the Pi include at least one similar LED / Microswitch project. But embedding the LED's in a wine shelf may be novel. With a bit of RFID tech you could probably come up with a useful idea, such as highlighting a number of suggested wines along a shelf, from a requirement entered on a smartphone (mobile computing device).

Comment: Appears they had a similar idea and posted it along with a demo of the [Smart wine shelf](https://labs.hybris.com/2014/06/18/video-the-smart-wine-shelf/) a year back.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to use patent database is google/patents. A little harder but more powerful is google patents advanced search. You could search for key words that you expect to be in the application. It might have been filed in the name of that company or some principals in that company may be listed as inventors.

If they have only filed a provisional application it will not be visible. A non-provisional application might not be visible for 18 months from filing. If they state to the USPTO  they are not patenting out of the country they could have elected to have it not be visible until the day it issues - if it issues.

Answer (score 1):

That blog post you link to also does not make any sense. They announce their intention to file for patent "in September" in a post dated July - complete with a fairly detailed system diagram. They better hope the examiner does not become aware of this, as this would constitute prior art for their own application! In any case, since they brag about their upcoming patent application publicly on their blog, why not ask them directly about their application serial number? In any case, as George already wrote, if they only filed this past September, it will take a while until the application is published.